# Can in-page anchors link to themselves for SEO?

Tags: seo, html, links, anchor

My page has a lot of sections. Each section has a unique anchor tag like `<h2 id="anchor-text">`.

Is it a good practice to link anchors to themselves `<h2 id="anchor-text"><a href="#anchor-text">Title</a></h2>`? Will it hurt SEO somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Hurt? No reason why it would.
I just don't understand why you would want to do that in the first place.

What you can do which does have an impact is creating page-jumps and putting that at the beginning of an article (or as a floating sidebar) for quick navigation of an article:

Example:

```
<a href="/internallinks.html#section-names">
```

That way Google might show them directly as a search result as well:

Wikipedia results often do that:
[image: inner-links Wikipedia]

Comment: If in page anchors link to themselves, users have the potential to find them.   They typically don't appear in the URL bar as the user scrolls the page, so it is more difficult for users to link to them than page links.

Comment: Because without such anchors it's hard to copy urls linked to specific  section of the site when you want to share link. I'm building list directory https://bitcoinbookmarks.com/ and I don't know what will be the best way for seo and visitors to get links to specific section if I will not link them to themselves. Maybe little icon with anchor near the title of the section will be better? It's is all about in-page navigation, because it's one page site.

Comment: @Bookmarks That's fine. If you also get some external backlinks to those titles, Google should start showing the inner links in search as well (under the main result).

Comment: @jet Thanks, I only worry that regular user will click thouse titles with anchors and will not understand what is going on. I guess they don't know what is `#some-text` in links.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, anchors with internal links to themselves don’t hurt, but I don’t see a reason why you should do it. On web content that directs visitors back to the same web content, such an anchor, at least in my opinion, has no added value.

Comment: This doesn't say anything the other answer doesn't already say and there are comments on the other answer addressing the issue about why you might want to do it.